# Can't set lightning component controller

Tags: controller, lightning-aura-components, namespace, trailhead

I am following the Trailhead "Create a Lightning Component" tutorial and I have reached the part where I have build the controller (Apex) and I am attempting to set the aura:component controller.

My Developer org has a namespace prefix set due to an earlier tutorial and I think it is conflicting. When I try and set the controller:

```
<aura:component controller="MyContactListController">

</aura:component>
```

I receive the following error:

> Failed to save undefined: No CONTROLLER named
>   apex://devprefix.MyContactListController found: Source

any idea why my controller is not being accessed under the namespace prefix? In case you are wondering I am posting the contents of the apex class below:

```
public class MyContactListController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> getContacts() {
        return [Select Id, Name, Email, Title, Phone From Contact];
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are doing this in the developer console, does your `MyContactListController` file name tab have a `.apxc` suffix or a `.js` suffix?

Comment: It has an apxc extension

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to recreate the issue, and although I don't know what is causing it, I was able to get past it by changing the name of the apex class:

```
public class MyContactListControllers {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> getContacts() {
        return [Select Id, Name, Email, Title, Phone From Contact];
    }
}
```

and then making the corresponding change in the component:

```
<aura:component controller="MyContactListControllers">

</aura:component>
```

Oddly after doing that, I could revert them back to their previous names and they would save without issue.

Comment: Same Happened with me.I guess the issue was the space after the class name.After i removed the space after the class name in my apex controller, the error was gone. Puff!!!!